# Visible Regex in input element with "live" validation

Tags: jquery, regex, security, dom-manipulation

so i am thinking about possible security-problems, that could occur because of my following setup:

I write the regex-code in a data-part of a text-input field. And while typing i am validating the user-input against the regex with jquery.

My security-thoughts are: Am i opening security holes while validating regex-code that could (technically) be manipulated by any user via, for example, the developer-tools of a browser?

This is how my input looks like:

```
<input id="email-regex-asd" type="text" data-regex="/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/">
```

Edit:
Just to make it clear: I am still validating the complete user-input in the backend to prevent SQL-injection, crossite-scripting, etc.

Comment: Always validate on the back-end.  Front-end validation is a bonus to improve the UX, it's never for security.

Comment: In my application i have to make front-end-validation. So in your opinion there are no security-holes?

Comment: In my opinion, if you have only front-end validation then you have *only* security holes.  There's 0 security in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

No security concern with the example provided.

The comparison is an application with front-end & back-end validation vs one with just back-end. If having the front-end validation improves nicety and/or performance, more power to you.